# Missing dependency when building with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to build the [Polycode](https://github.com/ivansafrin/Polycode) codes using CMake. I followed the instructions in the [Build.md](https://github.com/ivansafrin/Polycode/blob/master/BUILD.md) file, but I get the following error:

```
$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..
No POLYCODE_RELEASE_DIR specified, to C:/Development/Polycode/Release/Windows
DEBUG CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Development/Polycode/Release/Windows/Framework/Core/Dependencies;C:/Development/Polycode/Release/Windows/Framework/Modules/Dependencies;C:/Development/Polycode/Release/Windows/Framework/Tools/Dependencies
CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:85 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMake/PolycodeIncludes.cmake:14 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  Core/Contents/CMakeLists.txt:2 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I see that it needs ZLIB but, I don't know how to handle this. Shouldn't it download the dependency automatically? I could surely find ZLIB and download it but I don't really want to do this with every single lib it might need. Is there a convenient way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a two-step build process. First you need to build the dependencies:

```
cd Dependencies  # <---- this will run the next steps in the Dependencies subdirectory of your Polycode repo
mkdir Build
cd Build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..
```

This step should install the required libraries. Only then you can you proceed to build Polycode itself

```
# <---- this build step is run inside your Polycode root directory
mkdir Build
cd Build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..
```

Comment: @nosferat no problem, it is easy to gloss over that as the difference is in the single line `cd Dependencies`.